# How to add a checkbox like "I agree following terms & conditions..."

Tags: civievent, custom-fields

I would like to add a mandatory checkbox on one of our event registration page. How can I do that please?

Comment: you can add one but still you need to associate the custom field value against participant record and not against Event

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can definitively do that with a custom field! Custom Field -> Used for: Participants -> choose Field Type: checkbox; make one multiple choice option (Label: 'I agree to the terms and conditions'); or: Label: 'Read, Understood and Accepted'.

Stick this new Custom Field into its own profile (so it can can have its own pre-form and/or post-form 'help' i.e. Terms and Conditions) -> make it required (in the profile) so users can't proceed without agreeing/checking the box.

Finally -> stick that profile into your Event Registration page (Event Config -> in the Online Registration tab).

Comment: This is exactly what we do too - except we put it on the contact record as general 'terms and conditions'. Then we don't need them to tick that box every time if they're logged in =]

Comment: Right! We use a variety: 1) on Participant -> Waivers eg  - for specific Events; 2) on Membership -> Confidentiality agreement eg specific to a Board position; 3) on Individual -> for very general Terms & Conditions